# Java Garbage Collection GcInfo.getDuration() changed unit from milli to microseconds

Tags: java, logging, garbage-collection, garbage

I am currently dealing with a little annoyance with the Class com.sun.management.GcInfo.
I improved our server log by adding a GC Notification Listener. Whenever a Major GC Takes place I log the duration it took (and some other stuff).
The "official" way is to add a Notification Listener for the GarbageCollectorMXBean beans.
Everything works as expected. I get informed about GC's and for each GarbageCollector I get a 
com.sun.management.GcInfo Object with a duration. My annoyance is that the current documentation 7u51 states the value of the duation is in milli seconds.
I ran our server application under 7u11 also, and the duration seems to be higher by the factor of 1000 => microseconds.
Does anyone have an information about that? In which Java version did they change that?

Comment: Hi!i have the same kind of problem but with start and end tme fro this class. My server is running with oracle jdk 7u6 and i have strange results for start and end time: 1530938772677. This value is described in the API as the number of milliseconds since the JVM has started... so the value make no sense. It is not also an epoch time because the value wul be in the future. I can't see any info on this...

Answer (score 1):

This is a [bug](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7087969) in JVM. GcInfo methods returns **ticks** instead of milliseconds.

That's what bug description says:

> When grabbing GarbageCollectorMXBean from the ManagementFactory, it is NOW possible (in Java 7) to cast the underlying bean implementation into a NotificationBroadcaster and add a NotificationListener.  Doing this causes the JVM to report on GC events after they're done.  In the JVM, GCNotifier::pushNotification puts the "raw" GCStatInfo data (containing start/end ticks) onto the request queue.  GCNotifier::sendNotification constructs GcInfo from this data WITHOUT converting the ticks to millis.  When the listener gets access to the GcInfo object, a call to getDuration() returns elapsed ticks vs. elapsed millis (contrary to comments in the source code).

So, you should use JVM version 7u51 or higher to get correct GC info.